# malloc and memory leaks in objective c

Tags: memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a problem with memory leaks when using malloc in objective c.
here's the code:

.h (interface)

```
{
    char *buffer[6];
    NSInteger fieldCount;
}

-(void)addField:(NSString *)str;
```

.m (implementation)

```
-(void)addField:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *helloworld =str;

    if (bufferData[5] != nil) {

        /*
         clear buffer
         */

        for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
            bufferData[i] = nil;
        }
        fieldCount = 0;
    }

    bufferData[fieldCount] = malloc(helloworld.length);
    char *ptrBuff = bufferData[fieldCount];

    for (int i = 0; i<helloworld.length; i++) {
        *ptrBuff++ = [helloworld characterAtIndex:i];
    }

    [self printBuffer];
    fieldCount ++;
}

-(void)printBuffer
{
    NSLog(@"buffer data %ld = %s",(long)fieldCount,bufferData[fieldCount]);
}
```

So basically I have 4 following classes below:

1. ViewController -> UIViewController
2. RootClass -> NSObject
3. ChildClass1 -> RootClass
4. Child -> Root Class

Additionally:

- Init process of the three classes are inside `-viewDidLoad` method.
- Both childClass1 and childClass 2 have a timer to call `-addField` method at the same time.

When I check my memory instrument, I have found a leak object every time it called
`-addField` method. It refers to this statement:

```
malloc(sizeof(*bufferData));
```

Can somebody help to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume with `malloc(sizeof(*bufferData))` you meant `malloc(helloworld.length)` above (since that's the only `malloc` call I see in your example).

The memory leak occurs when you clear your buffer:

```
bufferData[i] = nil;
```

This leaks because you allocated the buffer contents using `malloc` but did not free them later using `free`. Note that even under ARC you must `free` any `malloc`ed resources yourself. ARC only provides management for Objective-C object instances.

The correct way to free the buffer here is:

```
free(bufferData[i]);
bufferData[i] = NULL;
```